# Number format converting

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a currency amount value like this;

```
22200000
```

I want to convert this number to;

```
22,2  (Number format)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I found the answer: 
    SELECT  TO_CHAR (22200000 / 1000000, '999,999,999,999.99') FROM    dual

Comment: Please add your own answer from the comment as an real answer and accept it by your own!

Comment: Write that what you had written in your comment into the "Your Answer" field down this site! And then accept it as the correct answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer: SELECT TO_CHAR (22200000 / 1000000, '999,999,999,999.99') FROM dual

Comment: You might want to consider using non-locale-specific syntax, i.e. `D` for decimal indicator and `G` for grouping separator, e.g. `TO_CHAR(22200000 / 1000000, '999G999G999G999D99')`. This way the formatting will be correct no matter what locale the client is using (e.g. Europeans would expect `999.999.999.999,99`, I believe).

Answer (score 5):

use `to_char()` function. Example

```
to_char(3510.78, '$9,999.00')
```

would return

```
 $3,510.78
```

Comment: select to_char(22200000,'$9,999.00') from dual  Result: ##########

Comment: hm, OP's mentioned number, you've mentioned currency?

Comment: @Sathya: yake swami, henga madidara, nandu answer correct allawenari swamy?

Comment: @Sathya: yene aagali, nimma jyothe matyadi santosh aaytu, nimmavare-

Comment: @Ravindrabagale he didn't mention it at first, he did now. I didn't downvote you.

Comment: The OP didn't mention that he wanted it *formatted* with a currency symbol. Also, even if they did, using `$` as the symbol may still be incorrect - he didn't say it was in dollars.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Oracle Built-in function round().

> The ROUND function accepts a number and returns another number rounded
>   to the specified number of places to the right of the decimal point.
>   If you do not specify that number, ROUND will return a number rounded
>   to the nearest integer

For instance:

```
    select 1/3, round(1/3, 2) from dual;

       1/3 ROUND(1/3,2)
---------- ------------
.333333333          .33
```

More info: [Working with Numbers in PL/SQL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-nov/o61plsql-512011.html)